# Loading multiple R packages with a single command

Tags: r, package, pacman-package-manager

Multiple `R` packages may be loaded using the function `p_load` function from `pacman` `R` package with the following command:

```
pacman::p_load("ggplot2", "lme4")
```

However, I want to use the command like this

```
Packages <- c("ggplot2", "lme4")
pacman::p_load(Packages)
```

which does not work. Wonder how this can be achieved?

Comment: I deem this to be a phenomenally bad idea. Load one package per line. Not a fan of `pacman::p_load` either, for that reason. We frown at people for declaring multiple variables on the same line. We should do the same for loading several packages on the same line, for the exact same reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `character.only` on `TRUE`

```
Packages <- c("ggplot2", "lme4")
Packages %in% loadedNamespaces() # check if the packages are loaded
# [1] FALSE FALSE

pacman::p_load(Packages, character.only = TRUE)

Packages %in% loadedNamespaces()
# [1] TRUE TRUE
```

From `?p_load`:

> "`character.only` : logical. If TRUE then p_load will only accept a single input which is a character vector containing the names of packages to load."

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, do `do.call(p_load, packages)`.

You can also do this without Pacman:

```
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

But as others have said, not recommended because it reduces clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Use argument `char` in `p_load` function.

> char: Character vector containing packages to load

```
foo <- c("data.table", "ggplot2")
pacman::p_load(char = foo)
```